# Bind Single object to Datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a class `Customer` with following members.

```
class Customer
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
}

class Test
{
    private void load()
    {
        Customer objCust=new Customer();
        objCust.ID="1";
        objCust.Name="Hello";
        objCust.Age="23";
    }
}
```

Now I want to bind this entity to my DataGridView, but it doesn't show me any row.

I used the following code to bind this Class object to my DataGridView.

```
datagridview1.DataSource = objCust;
```

Answer (score 6):

Generally a data source for a grid is a collection.  (I'm not really sure *what* it would do when trying to bind to something over which it can't enumerate.  Perhaps it just ignores it, resulting in the behavior you're seeing.)  If you only want one item in that collection, initialize a single-item collection for it:

```
datagridview1.DataSource = new List<Customer> { objCust };
```

or even:

```
datagridview1.DataSource = new Customer[1] { objCust };
```

Comment: @MikeChristensen: Perhaps indeed.  I went ahead and added it as another example.  Thanks!

Comment: @David thanx alot now my datagridview is showing the data. But can you tell me why we are unable to bind single entity to a datagridview.

Comment: @TikamSangwani  Ienumerable,Ilist interface requirements......,for example if u use a bindingsource and set its datasource to typeof(Customer),internaly the bindingsource will initialize a bindinglist<T>(where t is customer) or simply adding the first item to the bindingsource will set its internal list to that type.

Comment: @TikamSangwani: Personally I think the `DataSource` property should enforce this, but that might cause other problems in people's code. *Technically* it's just an `Object` so the compiler lets you set *anything* to that property. But consider it logically... A grid shows a set of records. Even if there's just one in the set, it's still a set. If you tried to treat an object itself as a set of objects, what would it show? What would each line item in the grid be? It doesn't really make sense to tell the grid to "show all of the records in this one `Customer`."

Comment: @TikamSangwani i strongly recommend  (if you want of course) to read up this book about databinding world,at the end of it you will nevermore think "black-magic" happening lol - http://www.amazon.com/Data-Binding-Windows-Forms-2-0/dp/032126892X/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1384192169&sr=1-1&keywords=data+binding